# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I have created Spring boot application with html but getting error 
    "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Project Structure:

```
TeamTrack
    --Src
       --Main
          --java
             --com.tm.controller
                  --application
                  --CertificateController
                  --WebConfig
          --resources
             ---static
                --app.js
       --Test
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("com.tm.vo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.tm.repository")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

CertificateController.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class CertificateController {

    @Autowired
    private certificateRepository certRep;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cert",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "certificate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCertificate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewCertificate(@RequestParam String certName,@RequestParam String certProvider)
    {
        certificate cert =new certificate();
        cert.setCertificateName(certName);
        cert.setCertificateProvider(certProvider);

        certRep.save(cert);
        return "/";
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/js/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/static/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations(
                    CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }
}
```

certificate.html

in the certificate.html , just calling the java script and its angular.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Error Details:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app.js] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

In chrome, In the Developer tool, got this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

can anyone help on this ?

Comment: I have added the below code in the Webconfig but still getting the error. @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

Comment: I missed certificate.html code and just pasted below                                                 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListController">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>

Comment: I think, you just need to add "/" before app.js. In this way <script src="/app.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your own configuration multiple times.

Change your `Application` class to reflect this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.tm.vo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.tm.repository")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Remove all `@EnableWebMvc`, since those disable MVC auto-configuration by Boot. Then completely delete your `WebConfig` class.

Answer (score 0):

Although, you've added the resourceHandlers in your WebConfig, I don't believe you're referencing the javascript correctly in your jsp.

try this:

```
<script src="/static/app.js"></script>
```

I've generally done it the following though:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/app.js"></script>
```